# Read data from clob

Tags: sql, select, oracle11g, clob

I have a table with a column defined as clob. The data in the clob column is written as, "limit":"10"

Table:

```
ID  COLA  
1  (CLOB)
```

Data in the COLA: `"limit":"10"`

Can someone please suggest me how do I query the the table to output the data from clob column.

desired output:

```
ColA  
10
```

Thanks
Pavan

Comment: Why are you using a CLOB for small amounts of data - or do you have rows with lots of entries? And why are you storing delimited data in one row, instead of relationally? Basically like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23649813/266304) though, but with a colon instead of a comma; except you have to deal with the quotes too. Can you have a colon within a quoted value?

Comment: unfortunately that is how it is. I don't have power to change the way the data is loaded.

Comment: What is the algorithm you are trying to use?  Fetch anything after the first colon and trim the double quotes from both sides?  Are you guaranteed that there is only one colon and only one pair of values in the column?