# How to split a column into two columns when there are multiple delimiters

Tags: sql, oracle

Source column

---

```
Id   | email
_______________________
01   | aemail1, wemail2
02   | bemail1 : xemail2
03   |  cemail1  yemail2
04   | demail1&zemail2
```

Target column

```
Id | primary_email| secondary_email
01 | aemail1      | wemail2
02 | bemail1      | xemail2
03 | cemail1      | yemail2
04 | demail1      | zemail2
```

In some cases where <space> is also a delimiter can we do using SQL if not pl/SQL please help me how to solve this

Comment: Seems like you've learned the lesson now - never store data in the same column as separated items.

Comment: The best way would be to normalize the table.

Comment: Here you can find some clues `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649813/split-comma-seperated-values-of-a-column-in-row-through-oracle-sql-query`

Comment: Here am using multiple delimiters not a single delimiter here & is also included, if I use & it pop-up for run time data input. So help me how to do in SQL and don't want to change anything from source

Comment: Can you list down all the possible delimiters your `email` column may contain? Will there be any special characters in the `email` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to split the emails into two.
This example splits on one or more consecutive delimiters `, or space or &`

```
select 
  ID, 
  regexp_replace(EMAIL, '^(.*)[,\s&]+.*', '\1') AS PRIMARY_EMAIL,
  regexp_replace(EMAIL, '.*[,\s&]+(.*)', '\1') AS SECONDARY_EMAIL 
from TABLE_NAME
```